# How can I initialize a Mat from double array?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to get a Mat:

```
Mat getMat(){
double data[9] = {0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0};  
Mat H = Mat(3, 3, CV_64FC1, data);  
return H;
}
```

In the main function I have:

```
cout << getMat() << endl;
```

But I get:

```
[9.803620554343549e-312, 9.815415529972478e-312, -5.314010372517808e+303;
 6.952533064904583e-310, 6.952533112667539e-310, 6.952533065625869e-310;
 6.952531771280892e-310, 6.952531720111155e-310, 1.30821040513014e-310]
```

when I print inside the function it works..

Comment: This code works as expected for me. Please double check that you posted the actual code

Comment: oh.. thank you.. Really I'm returning H from a function Mat getMat() and then i do cout<<geMat()

Comment: That doesn't help ;D . Please post a [mcve]

Comment: sorry, I have changed my post, does it help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `data` buffer will be deallocated once you exit the `getMat` function, so it will contain garbage.

You need to copy the data buffer with `clone()`:

```
Mat getMat(){
    double data[9] = {0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0};  
    Mat H = Mat(3, 3, CV_64FC1, data).clone();  
    return H;
}
```

For small matrices, you can also use:

```
Mat getMat(){
    Mat H = (Mat1d(3, 3) << 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 
                            3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 
                            6.0, 7.0, 8.0);
    return H;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand, but I do a Pre-calculate on h before return. I'll try with the first option you gave me..

Comment: It works. Thank you. I'll be more careful with blocks and deallocation.. :P